# React Native images will not show on one app, but will show on other fresh apps

Tags: ios, image, react-native

In my RN (ios based) app my images used to show perfectly, but for whatever reason stopped appearing. I keep them in an img folder labeled as 'home.png' etc.

I imported Image from react-native

`import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Image, Text, StatusBar, } from 'react-native';`

and attempt to display it in return section with:

`<Image source={require('./img/cool.jpg')}/>`

The image will not show regardless of png or jpg extension. It shows up gray.

I created a fresh RN app and repeated the above, importing Image & using:

`<Image source={require('./img/cool.jpg')}/>`

In the fresh app, the image shows no problem. What could possibly be doing this? I can't get the images to show on any of my screens for the app I'm working on.

Comment: You should provide more info about the code but maybe the style isn't suitable or it's behind something else!

Comment: Thanks. Didn't want to send too much info so people would get through it easier. I think it might be behind something since it's always solid gray for some reason. I'll review my code more, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, images BREAK after certain updates whether it be React native or iOS updates. An absolutely unbelievable headache that no one seems to have encountered before. Luckily, copying code logic to a new working app fixed it. I hope this NEVER occurs again.